# Magento 2 : Show admin category tree on frontend

Tags: magento2, frontend, category-tree

I want to display categories tree on frontend like admin default categories tree.

Need to display category tree structure in my custom module and content area for frontend side.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page

Comment: Not just show category name but need category with tree like same as admin.

Comment: Please refer: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/912
It will help you

Comment: @nikunjVadariya Thank you for your suggestion. Let me check.

Answer (score 5):

1) go to "app" from root directory of Magento 2 and create new directory code.
Then create two more directories in **app/code**, Namespace and Module Name. The final directory will look like this: **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree**.

**Demo** as **Namespace** and **CategoryTree** as module name.

2) create "module.xml" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/etc** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Demo_CategoryTree" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

3) create "route.xml" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/etc/frontend** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="categorytree" frontName="categorytree">
            <module name="Demo_CategoryTree" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

4) create "registration.php" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree** and paste below code in file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Demo_CategoryTree',
    __DIR__
);
```

5) create "Index.php" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/Controller/Index** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Demo\CategoryTree\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Renders CATEGORYTREE Index page
     *
     * @param string|null $coreRoute
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Forward
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */
    public function execute($coreRoute = null)
    {
        $resultPage =  $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('CategoryTree'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

6) create "categorytree_index_index.xml" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/view/frontend/layout** and paste below code into the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <head>
        <css src="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css"/>
        <css src="extjs/resources/css/ytheme-magento.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Tree" name="category.tree" template="Demo_CategoryTree::catalog/category/tree.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

7) copy from **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/category/tree.phtml** to **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/view/frontend/templates/catalog/category**

8) create "requirejs-config.js" file in **app/code/Demo/CategoryTree/view/frontend** and paste below code into the file:

```
var config = {
    "shim": {
        "extjs/ext-tree": [
            "prototype"
        ],
        "extjs/ext-tree-checkbox": [
            "extjs/ext-tree",
            "extjs/defaults"
        ]
    }
};
```

9) Run below commands in the root directory:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

10) run url like this "http://local-magento.com/categorytree/index/index" 
so you will get output like below.

[image]

Comment: hi @nilesh gosai could u please help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249360/how-to-add-category-tree-at-attribute-level-in-magento-2-using-ui-components-con